# How does LinkedIn determine whether to show a not-signed-in user a profile or login screen when viewing a profile?

Tags: linkedin

For those without a LinkedIn account (or a user who's simply not logged in), it appears somewhat random as to whether it will be possible to view profile pages - sometimes they load as expected, and other times a login screen with the blurred background is rendered instead (presumably to prompt the user to login).

I am curious as to the bases on which LinkedIn determines whether to display the actual profile page or the blurred version with login. I suspect it may be:

- based on IP (or IP range)
- based on repeat site views
- based on the device/browser you're viewing the site through (or user-agent)
- something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is up to the users to decide if they want their profile to be visible for guest.

Find the setting at https://www.linkedin.com/public-profile/settings or via this path:

```
Me / Profile & Settings / Privacy / Edit your public profile / Edit visibility
```

Comment: Wow-that's it? I hadn't even thought of that! No wonder it seemed kinda random

Comment: It's not that simple. I have made my profile public, but can't see it when using the profile URL in an incognito window. If I google my name, however, the LinkedIn page comes up, and if I click it, it displays.

Answer (score 1):

There is some logic behind it.  Even if the user has made profile public, it may ask visitor to login. You can try same from different laptops you may see different result. Perhaps based on cookies dropped in the browser.